# How to use select In query in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I want to call same Article model with articleAmmendment and followers

```
$data['ammendmentcontent'] = Article::with('articleAmmendments','sections.sectionContent','sections.regulations','sections.schedules','sections.caselaws','relatedBook','relatedRegulations','relatedSchedules','relatedcaselaw.Content','relatedBook.relatedActs','tamiltranslation','sinhalatranslation','followers')->where('slug',$id)->first();
```

Comment: So, where's the problem?

Comment: i don't know ho to do  ?